# How to use System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: xamarin.ios, system.drawing.color

I've faced with problem yesterday. I want to use `System.Drawing.Color` structure in Android and iOS projects. Xamarin documentation claims that MonoTouch framework has `System.Drawing.Color` structure (link - http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:System.Drawing.Color). But in monotouch.dll namespace `System.Drawing` hasn't structure with name Color.
[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a reference to the `OpenTK` library and you'll have `System.Drawing.Color` available. The doc you linked was indicating it:

[image: doc screenshot]

To add a reference: double click on `Reference` in your project, and under the **All* tab, select OpenTK,

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see it.

Comment: np. that's why I highlighted it.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states "System.Drawing.Color Structure", i.e. not 
namespace. This means you cannot do something like "using 
System.Drawing.Color;" in C#.

For all your color needs in iOS, you need to use [MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor), the type that MonoTouch uses in most cases (e.g. all the UIKit API).

I am not sure for Android, but I guess you need to use [Android.Graphics.Color](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Graphics.Color)

Comment: I don't use it as "using System.Drawing.Color". Just do "using System.Drawing and try to use Color". I know about UIColor, but in platform independent code I want to use something common and in iOS/Android implementation get UIColor/Graphics.Color from Drawing.Color.

Comment: I'm with Alexander on this one — it's silly for System.Drawing to include points, rects, etc., and not include some generic representation of colors.  I'm not comfortable having to add OpenTK just to get System.Drawing.Color... is there some good reason this structure is omitted from MonoTouch?